# Updating values from excel to database

Tags: c#, sql

I am facing difficulty on writing logic to insert data into the database from some array. My requirement is if the data already exist in SQL insert query should not be executed. only when that data does not exist in database the insert query has to be executed where data will be inserted. I have tried a lot please find my code below.

```
public void writetodatabase()
    {
        //SQL connection String
        SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=ABDUL-TPS\TPSSQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=Automation;Integrated Security=True");

        // Open Connection to sql
        cnn.Open();

        // Declare a DataTable which will contain the result from SQL query
        DataTable DT = new DataTable();
        for(int m =0; m < globalZoho_Names.Length; m++)
        {
            string query1 = "select * from tbl_Zoho_data where col_Zoho_SKU like '" + globalZoho_SKU[m] + "'";
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(query1, cnn);
            SqlDataReader reader1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader1.Read())
            {

                string zohosku = reader1["col_Zoho_SKU"].ToString();


                if (zohosku == null)
                {
                    string ItemName = reader1["col_item_name"].ToString();
                    string insert1 = "insert into tbl_zOHO_DATA values ('" + globalZoho_SKU[m] + "','" + globalZoho_Names[m] + "')";
                    SqlDataAdapter DA_insert = new SqlDataAdapter(insert1, cnn);
                    DA_insert.Fill(DT);
                    Label1.Text = "Khulja Sim Sim";
                }

            }
            reader1.Close();
        }
    }
```

I want the code to check for the values first into the database and then insert only those values which do not exist in the database.

Comment: Please update details indicating where you're having issues.  Is the error occurring on checking the DB for the data or the insert?  Is it both?

Comment: Neither it is checking the DB nor it is inserting data if it does not exist in DB

Comment: if the result of the "select" query is empty then insert query has to be executed.